# using dplyr to create new columns based on condition from data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create new columns in my data based on the dates.

What I would like to do is to get the data in the following format:

```
        dates  yes_no grp event    2017-01-02     2017-01-04
1  2017-01-01     364   1    NA       NA            NA
2  2017-01-02    2451   1     1        1            NA
3  2017-01-03   32440   1    NA       NA            NA
4  2017-01-04  234341   1     1       NA             1
5  2017-01-05  123443   1    NA       NA            NA
6  2017-01-01    7273   2    NA       NA            NA
7  2017-01-02    2331   2     1        1            NA
8  2017-01-03   12332   2    NA       NA            NA
9  2017-01-04   12233   2     1       NA             1
10 2017-01-05 1232323   2    NA       NA            NA
```

I have 2 groups `grp` 1 and 2. The event happens on the `2017-01-02` and `2017-01-04` for both groups. I am trying to create a single column for each of these two dates and populate the column if the event occurs on that date.

I originally thought about using `case_when` and then `pivot_wider` using the following:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(event = case_when(
    dates == "2017-01-02" ~ 1,
    dates == "2017-01-04" ~ 1
  )) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = dates, values_from = yes_no)
```

This doesn't work on my data because I run into memory issues and I do not want to create a column for each date, just the dates which has the `event = 1`. Alternatively it might be useful to create the columns manually and then populate the date directly.

i.e.
d$`2017-01-02` = 0
ifelse(dates = "2017-01-02", `2017-01-02` = 1, 0)

However I have about 30 dates I want to populate and create new columns.

Data:

```
   d <- data.frame(
  dates = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05",
            "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05"),
  yes_no = c(0364, 2451, 32440, 234341, 123443,
             7273, 2331, 12332, 12233, 1232323),
  grp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `lapply` to add new columns

```
dates = c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-04")
d[dates] <- lapply(dates, function(x) ifelse(d$dates == x, 1, NA))
d

#        dates  yes_no grp 2017-01-02 2017-01-04
#1  2017-01-01     364   1         NA         NA
#2  2017-01-02    2451   1          1         NA
#3  2017-01-03   32440   1         NA         NA
#4  2017-01-04  234341   1         NA          1
#5  2017-01-05  123443   1         NA         NA
#6  2017-01-01    7273   2         NA         NA
#7  2017-01-02    2331   2          1         NA
#8  2017-01-03   12332   2         NA         NA
#9  2017-01-04   12233   2         NA          1
#10 2017-01-05 1232323   2         NA         NA
```

In `purrr` `lapply` can be replaced with `map`

```
d[dates] <- purrr::map(dates, ~ifelse(d$dates == .x, 1, NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you create the date columns explicitly?

```
d %>% 
  mutate(event = case_when(
    dates == "2017-01-02" ~ 1,
    dates == "2017-01-04" ~ 1
  ),
  `2017-01-02` = ifelse(dates == "2017-01-02", 1, NA),
  `2017-01-04` = ifelse(dates == "2017-01-04", 1, NA),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (mostly) tidy solution that works well if you have more than the two dates you mention:

```
library(dplyr)
dates <- c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-04")
d %>% 
  {
    l <- lapply(dates, function(x) ifelse(x == .$dates, 1, NA))
    names(l) <- dates
    cbind(., l)
  } %>% 
  mutate(event = select(., starts_with("201")) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
#>         dates  yes_no grp 2017-01-02 2017-01-04 event
#> 1  2017-01-01     364   1         NA         NA     0
#> 2  2017-01-02    2451   1          1         NA     1
#> 3  2017-01-03   32440   1         NA         NA     0
#> 4  2017-01-04  234341   1         NA          1     1
#> 5  2017-01-05  123443   1         NA         NA     0
#> 6  2017-01-01    7273   2         NA         NA     0
#> 7  2017-01-02    2331   2          1         NA     1
#> 8  2017-01-03   12332   2         NA         NA     0
#> 9  2017-01-04   12233   2         NA          1     1
#> 10 2017-01-05 1232323   2         NA         NA     0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you don't like how this looks you can move the loop into a function to accomplish the same:

```
add_date_column <- function(tbl, dates) {
    l <- lapply(dates, function(x) ifelse(x == tbl$dates, 1, NA))
    names(l) <- dates
    cbind(tbl, l)
}
d %>% 
  add_date_column(dates) %>% 
  mutate(event = select(., starts_with("201")) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this in `base R` with

```
dates = c("2017-01-02", "2017-01-04")
d[dates] <- NA^(sapply(dates, `!=`, d$dates))
```